# problem executing trigger in MySQL error 1442

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

The objective is that the trigger updates the customer column last_update every time a customer gets an update.

I built the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateCustomer 
`BEFORE UPDATE ON customer 
 FOR EACH ROW 
 UPDATE customer
 SET last_update = current_timestamp()
 WHERE c_id = NEW.c_id;`
```

But I get the following error:

> 0 16  07:37:43    UPDATE customer SET is_active = TRUE    Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'customer' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.  0.000 sec

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: seems,in this case you need AFTER UPDATE trigger

Comment: You shouldn't do this in the trigger. Simply alter the column definition and add `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to it - the value will be updated automatically without any trigger.

Comment: I'm relatively new to SQL. How do I alter the column definition? An example could help. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value.  This is a *before* update trigger, so the update will use the new value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateCustomer 
BEFORE UPDATE ON customer 
FOR EACH ROW 
    SET new.last_update = current_timestamp();
```

Comment: ok, that works, but is there a way to only set the time stamp in the customer that was updated? It doesn't want to take the where clause

Comment: @JuanPabloClavijo set NEW.last_update = ... but Akina's comment on your question is a better solution